# How to contatenate React JSX objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I would like to add `<p>` tag in `ExtendedComponent` by calling `super.render()`, Problem is I don't know whether it is possible to modify already defined jsx object. Ideal would be to just write `parentTemplate + <p>Some paragraph</p>`, but that doesn't work.

```
class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
  get title() {
    return 'I am base component';
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>Hello {this.title}</h1>;
  }
}

class ExtendedComponent extends BaseComponent {
  get title() {
    return 'I am extended component';
  }

  render() {
    var parentTemplate = super.render();
    // append <p>Some paragraph</p> to parentTemplate
    return parentTemplate;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ExtendedComponent />,       
  document.getElementById('test')
);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity why do this pattern? Why not just two components where one wraps the other inside `render` ?

Comment: That just feels more natural for me, especially when I would like to adjust both render and another method in a child component. In this case I feel I would need to extend a component first to adjust some method, and then wrap it in another component in its render method to add more html. My method would kill two birds with one stone

Comment: If you can make it work for you, I guess that's fine, however you won't see this very often in React code. Inheritance is a pain to maintain, and with things like higher order components, component composition is easy to achieve. If you're willing to forgo the inheritance model, I'll gladly provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like azium mentioned in the comments, this is not common to do with react. However, if you need to do it, it can be accomplished like this:

```
render() {
  var parentTemplate = super.render();
  // append <p>Some paragraph</p> to parentTemplate 
  return <div>{parentTemplate}<p>Some paragraph</p></div>;
}
```

You have to wrap it inside a div since a react element only can return one element, not a list of them. `parentTemplate` is just like any other jsx, but it's in a variable. You use the `{variableName}` syntax to add variables into the JSX.

Another way to do this, which is more "react"-like:

```
class BaseComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello {this.props.title}</h1>;
  }
}
BaseComponent.propTypes = {
  title: React.PropTypes.string
};
BaseComponent.defaultProps = {
  title: 'I am base component'
};

class ExtendedComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BaseComponent title="I am extended component"/>
        <p>Some paragraph</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ExtendedComponent />,       
  document.getElementById('test')
);
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/43970/)

Here `ExtendedComponent` is a higher-order component rather than one that inherits from BaseComponent. Most of the time this is a seperation of concerns that is easier to reason about, and most react apps are built this way rather than on inheritation.

Hope this helps!